# elasticsearch blocks inserting data using PostMan

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a new index putting the following settings:

```
"settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "blocks": {
                    "read_only_allow_delete": "false" // null was tested also
                },
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "autocomplete_filter": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": "1",
                            "max_gram": "20"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "autocomplete_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "2"
            }
        }
```

now when I index a new document for the first time using postman it is indexed correctly, but the next document issues an error, after the error I sent a GET request and I noticed that the settings became:

```
"settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "blocks": {
                    "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
                },
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "autocomplete_filter": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": "1",
                            "max_gram": "20"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "autocomplete_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "2"
            }
        }
```

So how come the `"read_only_allow_delete"` is set to `true` after the first document being indexed.
I verified the settings after creating the index and it was not `false` 
The error:

```
403 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your elasticsearch cluster disk space is running low. See the flood stage watermark setting on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/disk-allocator.html) page